Как ссылаться на проекты с одинаковым префиксным названием
Существует проект CompanyEmployees, который ссылается на CompanyEmployees.Presentation
При добавлении следующего кода в первом проекте в Program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(CompanyEmployees.Presentation.AssemblyReference).Assembly);

ругается, и говорит что Presentation не существует в пространстве CompanyEmployees, как заставить его искать в другом проекте?

extern alias
